# onclick of href if on mobile redirect

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have created a website: http://idealweddingcarsni.com

On the six pictures on the home page I want a lightbox to come up with a bigger car picture and description, I have achieved this using slimbox:
http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2/

```html
<div class="block-link"> 
  <a href="images/page1_image1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Black & Ivory Royale Windsor - Seats up to 3 passengers.  Popular Choice for the Bride and Groom as their getaway car! The Royale Windsor is unique as it has a convertible fold down roof, which is amazing for photos." class="link">info</a>
</div>
```

The light box does not work on a mobile it just brings you to the image directly.  For a workaround I wanted the lightbox only to run if the screen width was bigger than a certain width. So I created an `id` in my `<a href>` and `onclick` of `id` (which is info button) redirects to 'contact us' page for more info.  This does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this help you http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?73180-Slimbox-to-work-with-mobiles ?

---

Sorry, I misunderstood your question, in the first place.

Maybe you can do something like that

```
var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) isMobile = true;

$( "a[rel='lightbox'] , a[rel='notaslimbox']").each( function() {
    var that = $( this );
    if( isMobile ) {
        that.attr( "imageLink" , that.attr( "href" ) );
        that.attr( "href" , "/contactus.html" );
        that.attr( "rel" , "notaslimbox" );
    }
    else if( that.attr( "rel" ) === "notaslimbox" ){
        that.attr( "href" , that.attr( "imageLink" ) );
        that.attr( "rel" , "lightbox" );
    }
} );
```

Or instead of mobile detection, you can just check the window size.
In this case, I would fire it each time you resize the window:
https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/kvqa99e2/2/

Comment: Put it into my index page but no luck, the same thing still happens where it loads the image in a new page by itself on mobiles.

Comment: @Alexandria 1) check your js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js script, it seems broken. 2) you need to change the rel as well (see updated answer) : https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/kvqa99e2/6/

Comment: @Alexandria no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand fully what you want to do,
but if you need a way to control your device resolution:

```
if($(window).width() < 500)
      {
       //Do something  
      }
```

500px is just as example.

Comment: on click off a href if the page is being viewed on mobile device i dont want lightbox to run I want the page to redirect but on desktop the light box can run.  Does that make sense, sorry didnt explain it well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to to your slimbox folder and open js folder open autoload.php file in there remove android, iPhone, exceptions...